# Print text when substring of array is found

Tags: google-sheets

Is there any formulas to produce Col-B below for substring matches of Col-A in Col-D and Col-E?

Reference

```
+------------+--------+
|   Col-D    | Col-E  |
+------------+--------+
| MCDONALD   | QOO10  |
| BURGERKING | AMAZON |
+------------+--------+
```

Expected Output

```
+----------------|------------------+
|     Col-A      |  Col-B (Output)  |
+----------------|------------------+
| MCDONALD LOC A | DINING           |
| MCDONALD LOC B | DINING           |
| BURGERKING     | DINING           |
| QOO10-ref-0001 | SHOPPING         |
| AMAZON-ref-002 | SHOPPING         |
+----------------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this formula:

`=ArrayFormula(if(REGEXMATCH(A2:A,JOIN("|",FILTER(D2:D,D2:D<>""))),"DINING",
  if(REGEXMATCH(A2:A,JOIN("|",FILTER(E2:E,E2:E<>""))),"SHOPPING","OTHER")))`

[image]

References:

- [REGEXEXTRACT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292)
- [JOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077?hl=en)
- [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en)

Comment: Instead of "OTHER" you can place no value after the comma and it will return a blank cell:  `=ArrayFormula(if(REGEXMATCH(A2:A,JOIN("|",FILTER(D2:D,D2:D<>""))),"DINING",
  if(REGEXMATCH(A2:A,JOIN("|",FILTER(E2:E,E2:E<>""))),"SHOPPING",)))`